# Slow Query Log returning wrong row examined

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

How the return number of rows this much, when there is only 20,000 rows i have in my database in given table. Please guide me in "row_examination". What does it mean?

```
 CALL DB.sp_get_program(10, 0, '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, '', '', @_cnet_param_p_total);
 Time: 150425  8:07:22
 User@Host: DB[User] @  [172.31.12.190]  Id: 64619
 Query_time: 62.843783  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 26264470

SELECT  (SELECT CONCAT(au.first_name,' ',au.last_name) FROM  tbl5 au WHERE admin_user_id = tbl.schedule_added_by LIMIT 1) as schedule_user_name,
(SELECT CONCAT(au.first_name,' ',au.last_name) FROM  tbl5 au WHERE admin_user_id = tbl.image_added_by LIMIT 1) as image_user_name,
(SELECT CONCAT(au.first_name,' ',au.last_name) FROM  tbl5 au WHERE admin_user_id = tbl.description_added_by LIMIT 1) as description_user_name,tbl.*
FROM
(SELECT *, 
(SELECT image FROM tbl WHERE program_id = p.program_id AND entry_type_id = 2 LIMIT 1) AS image,
(SELECT short_description FROM tbl WHERE program_id = p.program_id  AND entry_type_id = 3 LIMIT 1) AS short_description,                        
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE program_id = p.program_id 
                         AND is_live = TRUE) AS live_count
                        from tbl2 p 
                        INNER JOIN tbl3 pc on p.program_id=pc.program_id
                        INNER JOIN tbl pu on p.program_id=pu.program_id
                        INNER JOIN tbl4 c on pc.channel_id=c.channel_id         
                        WHERE pu.from_admin = FALSE AND p.is_active = TRUE
                        GROUP BY pc.program_channel_id) tbl WHERE  tbl.live_count < 3 AND (is_schedule_live= FALSE OR is_image_live=FALSE OR is_description_live=FALSE)
```

Comment: We can't tell - if you showed the source code for DB.sp_get_program() maybe we could take an educated guess.

Comment: I just wanted to know "rows_examined" consideration, Like what it includes in it, total number of rows in the main table, or  it includes sub queries, joins etc all.

Comment: It includes all of them - looks like you need to add some indexes. See the EXPLAIN plan for the query to identify where they are needed

Answer (score 0):

That smells like an accidental "cross join".  Check your code to see if each `JOIN` has an `ON` clause.

If you need more help,

- Provide source of stored program
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table
- sizes of the tables.

Comment: Is `admin_user_id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of `tbl5`?  And other questions for which I need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.